# make all in qualcomm cdb20

Tags: qualcomm

I am getting these two errors while doing `make all` in qualcomm cdb20

```
make: arm-none-eabi-gcc: Command not found

make: *** [qurt_init.o] Error 127*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Error No:127**, is returned if the tool chain path is not specified in environment variables.

The toolchain for Qualcomm cdb20 which supports both Windows and Linux platform can be downloaded from the
ARM website at: https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads

Supported version: 6.2

Once toolchain is downloaded, add the path of toolchain binaries to ‘PATH’ environment variable.

Linux:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bin
```

Windows:

```
set %PATH%=%PATH%:\path\to\bin
```

[kindly refer user guide provided by Qualcomm](https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/qca4020-qca4024/qca402x-cdb2x-development-kit-user-guide.pdf)